# Google Spreadsheet Filter Button Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a script available that would allow me to click a button to automatically filter in rows that meet the criteria that the button defines?

Comment: You can definitely write a Google Apps Script to do what you've mentioned and attach the script to a button. You can get started with the 5-minute quickstart guides ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros ). Start exploring and come back to SO with a specific problem if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to write it in gas. Also consider not using a script and instead use the Query function that spreadsheets have. You can make a parametrized query that pulls its parameters from other cells.